# If $S=1+\frac{1}{\sin x}+\frac{1}{\sin^2x}+...$ what's the measure of angle $x$?

Tags: geometric-series

If $S=1+\dfrac{1}{\sin x}+\dfrac{1}{\sin^2x}+...+\dfrac{1}{\sin^n x}+...=\dfrac23,$ what's the measure of angle $x$?

We have an infinite geometric series with first term $a_1=1$ and common ratio $q=\dfrac{1}{\sin x}$. Then $$S=\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{1}{\sin x}}=\dfrac{\sin x}{\sin x-1}=\dfrac{2}{3}\iff3\sin x=2\sin x-2\iff\sin x=-2, $$ which has no solutions. Am I making a silly mistake somewhere?

Comment: Hint: what can be said about $q$ if $|\sin x|\leq 1$?

Comment: @Yalikesifulei, I am not sure. Can you further clarify for me?

Comment: The equation is not right: $S=\frac {1-\frac 1{\sin^{n+1}x}}{1-\frac 1{\sin x}}=\frac 23$.

Comment: @WindSoul Even if it were a finite series, you'd want that exponent to be $n+1$.

Comment: @J.G., can you show me how from $-1\le\sin x\le1$ I can make a statement for $\dfrac{1}{\sin x}$? I really cannot see it.

Comment: Hint: what if $-1\le\sin x<0$? What if $\sin x=0$? What if $0<\sin x\le1$?

Answer (score 2):

This is a divergent serie.$|\sin(x)|\leq 1$ so the reciprocal is greater or equal to 1.
If you consider for example $\sin(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}$ you have $\dfrac{1}{\sin(x)}=2$
And the series became: $1+2+2^2+2^3+2^4+...\to\infty$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the geometric series
$$
S(x)=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\sin x)^{-n} \tag{1}
$$
converges, the OP showed that it equals $\frac{2}{3}$ if $\sin x=-2$. On the other hand, as
already explained by others, the series diverges if $x$ is real, for $|\sin x|\leq 1$. Now, although $\sin x=-2$ has no real solution, it has *complex* solutions. Indeed, if we write $x=u+iv$, where $u$ and $v$ are real, then$^{(*)}$
$$
\sin x = \sin(u+iv) = \sin u\cosh v + i\cos u \sinh v, \tag{2}
$$
hence
$$
\sin x = -2 \iff 
\begin{cases} 
    \sin u\cosh v = -2, \\
    \cos u\sinh v = 0.          
\end{cases} \tag{3}
$$
One can easily check that $(3)$ has the following solutions:
\begin{align}
u&=-\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi\quad(n=0,\pm1,\pm2,\ldots), \\
v&=\cosh^{-1}(2)=\pm\ln(2+\sqrt{3}), \tag{4}
\end{align}
therefore $S(x)=\frac{2}{3}$ at the "angles" $x=(-\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi)\pm i\ln(2+\sqrt{3})$ $(n=0,\pm1,\pm2,\ldots)$.

---

$^{(*)}$https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#In_the_complex_plane